# import conda packages into colaboratory jupyter

Tags: conda, google-colaboratory

I need some packages that can be installed only through conda (cannot with pip). 
I was able to install conda by downloading installer and then created virtual 
environment.

```
! wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
! bash Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p $HOME/anaconda
```

After that I installed needed packages into conda environment with conda install.

But I am not able to figure out how to run jupyter in conda virtual environment. As of now, it only runs default system python. (Please note I am trying to import conda packages into the jupyter environment to experiment and not trying to run any script (which I think can be done by activating conda environment and executing python script in a .sh file)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to import conda packages into google colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53000670/how-to-import-conda-packages-into-google-colab)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to just unzip the conda package to the right folder directly.

1. Search for the library you want on anaconda.org, then download it
2. Decompress it
3. Copy them into the library path
4. `!pip install` other required dependencies

Here's an example how I install `faiss` with this method.

https://gist.github.com/korakot/d0a49d7280bd3fb856ae6517bfe8da7a

Answer (score 0):

You run this for working of conda command

1.`!wget -c https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh`

2.`!chmod +x Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh`

3.`!bash ./Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local`

4.`!conda install -y --prefix /usr/local -c <<<your wish>>>>`

5`import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/')`

Now conda command will work like `!conda install pytorch==0.4`

Answer (score -1):

If you have a local conda environment that you'd like to use, one option is to connect to a local Jupyter backend using Colab. Instructions are here:
https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html