# how to import conda packages into google colab?

Tags: python, conda, google-colaboratory, cartopy

I was able to install packages in google colab with pip, using:

```
!pip install....
```

but i am not able to install any package from conda-forge. I tried:

```
!conda install -c conda-forge cartopy
```

Comment: If you only want to install `cartopy`, use `!apt-get -qq install python-cartopy python3-cartopy`.

Answer (score 4):

In general, this is a way to install a package in conda from Colab:

```
!wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh -bfp /usr/local
# Append path to be able to run packages installed with conda
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages')
# Install packages from Anaconda
!conda install -y [package]
```

This works for packages like `-c pslmodels taxcalc` ([notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12it6qb0sFBTgCN48Tl3VIr-TLpBvjtZQ#scrollTo=Tv2RjZWgYlw0)).

However, `cartopy` is a complicated package that's creating problems here, I think because the above requires an older version of `conda`*, which is no longer compatible with `cartopy`. Here's a [Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PWsd7I3rLqVmkx9rsSoJn5gdhwccSEB_) that uses this version and fails because `cartopy` requires the `shapefile` package, and [this is one](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NQHuKoK3IczyNz_6FZuZaRX7RgQppNzG) that uses the latest version of conda and isn't recognized upon `import`.

* For example, here are versions of the `taxcalc` notebook that [install the latest installer](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GUAQGyhhXi9sBER8voQ3IehzOrXBaUkj) and [run `conda update conda`](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10V59-Z8SbKUlIbOiOjwaSsTwUkOSs422) before installing `taxcalc`; `import taxcalc` isn't recognized in either case. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PSLmodels/Tax-Calculator/issues/2393).

Answer (score 1):

One way to get it is to just Unzip the `conda` package to a directory directly.

1. **Get you required `conda` package from `anaconda.org`, download it.**
2. **Decompress them and copy them into the library path**

Here's an example to install `faiss` from anaconda using this way.
https://gist.github.com/korakot/d0a49d7280bd3fb856ae6517bfe8da7a

Answer (score 0):

Another option (that I've not tried) is to connect to a custom runtime (kernel in Jupyter parlance). https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

The workflow would be:

- create a conda environment with the things you want + jupyter_http_over_ws
- start a notebook on your machine and [connect colab as described](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html)

This may not be what you are looking for though as it does require local installations (and is therefore no longer zero-install).

Answer (score 0):

I use the decompress method with cartopy. Here's the result.

```
# get package then extract
!wget https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/cartopy/0.16.0/download/linux-64/cartopy-0.16.0-py36h81b52dc_2.tar.bz2
!tar xvjf cartopy-0.16.0-py36h81b52dc_2.tar.bz2
!cp -r lib/python3.6/site-packages/* /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/
# install dependencies
!pip install shapely pyshp
!apt install libproj-dev libgeos-dev
# finally
import cartopy
```