# How do I install Anaconda in Google Colab

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda, conda, google-colaboratory, miniconda

Anaconda doesn't come pre-installed on Google Colab, but I want to use it to install and manage packages. How do I install it?

Comment: Duplicate: [how to import conda packages into google colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53000670/how-to-import-conda-packages-into-google-colab)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run the following in a code cell:

```
# Install conda and add channels to look for packages in
import sys
! wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh
! chmod +x Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh
! bash ./Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/')
! conda update -n base -c defaults conda -y
! conda config --add channels bioconda
! conda config --add channels conda-forge
```